# How can I pass a socket between instances on App Engine using the Go runtime?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

The Python runtime allows it by [pickling the connection](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/). Is there a similar way to share sockets using the Go runtime on classic App Engine with `google.golang.org/appengine/socket`?

Comment: I don't think it's possible since the socket that you instantiate will be runtime specific. Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The descriptor isn't exposed in the Go API: https://github.com/golang/appengine/blob/master/socket/socket_classic.go#L152

```
type Conn struct {
    ctx    context.Context
    desc   string
    offset int64

    prot          pb.CreateSocketRequest_SocketProtocol
    local, remote *pb.AddressPort

    readDeadline, writeDeadline time.Time // optional
}
```

`desc` is what you would need on the other side to reconstruct the socket.

It should be possible fork this library on GitHub, change the conn struct to expose the needed `desc` property, and then change the import to `github.com/YOURUSERNAME/appengine/socket` instead of `appengine/socket`.

It's a lot of work so if you can come up with a different way to solve this you're probably better off. Nevertheless it should be possible.